# Android:MySQL datas passing failed

Tags: android, mysql

I'm trying to get some datas from mysql DB and print its in a text view.
I'm working with a query that recognizes rows using a data passed by _POST with my application.

that's the .java:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendario);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    LoginClass ID_P =  ((LoginClass)getApplicationContext());
    id_user = ID_P.getID();
    Log.d("id_w?",id_user);


    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_pren);
    fill_text();

}

private void fill_text(){

    try{
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost = new HttpPost("******MY URI*******");
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        prenotazione = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        prenotazione.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_user",id_user));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(prenotazione));
        Log.d("gladdi",prenotazione.toString());
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        inputStream = entity.getContent();


        } 
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(CalendarioActivity.this, "error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
            if(inputStream != null){
            Log.d("glad2",id_user);
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                inputStream.close();
                result = sb.toString();

                Log.d("sort",result);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("TEST", "Errore nel convertire il risultato "+e.toString());
                }
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            prenotazioni = "";
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_pren = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                result_string = "Prenotazione in data "+json_pren.getString("data")+", "+json_pren.getString("dettagli")+"\n\n";
                prenotazioni = prenotazioni + result_string;
                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                    }   
        }else{
            //do nothing
        }

            text.setText(prenotazioni);
}//end fill_text()
```

....

If i use the query on the browser it works(replacing _POST -> _GET), but not when i launch the application ... it's like that the string "id_user" is not passed ...
I hope i was clear. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure it's just an oversight, but it helps to send the parameters BEFORE you get the results.

Change this:

```
    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    prenotazione = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    prenotazione.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_user",id_user));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(prenotazione));
```

to this:

```
    prenotazione = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    prenotazione.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_user",id_user));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(prenotazione));
    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```